# Is there any k8s deploy policy control tools I can use to implement some specific deploy policy?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

Due to some reasons, the deployment policy in my team is quite complicated now, for example:
deploy sequence must obey this sequence: qa cluster -> dev cluster -> prod cluster,
forbid deploy in Friday
some cluster deployment must have a time interval,
deploy to cluster in some specific region first, then the clusters in another region

Currently we do this by manual check, but it really takes too much time, are there any tools we can use for this?

Comment: Have you checked out [Open Policy Agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/)? OPA may help you enforcing advance policies.

Comment: I will personally suggest VS Code for Policy Authoring since your developers can use it as well